# How to remove unused css in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My page speed insights shows me to remove unused **css** what should I do?
Is there any plugin for `wordpress` to do so?
I am using *worpress*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

the longer answer:
unused CSS is a curse in environments such as WordPress (or Joomla or Drupal or …) as each theme/ plugin adds CSS which covers all of the use cases where the plugin (or theme) can be used in. this means that each individual CSS-file on your site has *a lot* of code in it that isn’t strictly needed on a random page of your site (or may even not be needed on your site at all).

there currently is no way to automate the removal of unneeded CSS, but you might be able to get some improvement using e.g. “plugin organizer” to only allow plugins to work on specific pages) and by creating a child theme that only has the CSS needed for your site (you’ll have to dequeue the parent theme CSS though).

ALso you can use `css and js minify wordpress` plugin that can also help you to run your site fast.e.g

```
Fast Velocity Minify
WP Super Minify
```